# How do I associate dropdown menu items with a set of foreign keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am currently making a web application to allow users to create, edit, and store tabletop RPG character information. This application is using ASP.NET MVC 5 for presentation, and Entity Framework 6 for DB access.

Currently, the design of my database that connects character information and their current race looks like this.

[image]
During character creation, I wish to display a dropdown list to the user, containing all the names of the individual playable races. However, when the character creation form is posted, I want the race's primary key to be inserted into that character's record, rather than the name itself.

How would I go about securely associating a key value with the name of the race in the dropdown list? Would I have to query the database to get the key, or is there an HTML helper method to securely bake the association between the two into a dropdown list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML select options have text, and a value. The text is displayed on the page, and the value is submitted with the form data. There is actually a nice HTML helper method for creating selects.

Here's an example of how you might use this in your situation:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RaceId,
    Model.Races.Select(race => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = race.Name, // displayed in the drop down list
        Value = race.Id,  // submitted to the controller for Model.RaceId
        Selected = Model.RaceId == race.Id // optionally select one of them
    }))
```

You can read more about this method [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2).